# Amazon AWS (Amazon AMI) installing OpenVPN

Tags: yum, openvpn, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up OpenVPN on AmazonAWS. I'm pretty new to Linux so I followed a tutorial. I ran `yum -y install openvpn`
and I received a message saying it was successfully installed. The next step was to copy the files in `/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/` to  `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/`.

Much to my surprise, the `/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/` directory was empty. I tried to uninstall and reinstall OpenVPN and the result was the same.

I tried to install easy-rsa separately, but I didn't find it in the yum package list. Can anyone help me install OpenVPN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this command to track those files down when an RPM is installed:

```
$ rpm -ql openvpn
```

and see where those files might actually be. For packages that haven't been installed yet you can query the `yum` repository using the command `repoquery`:

```
$ repoquery -l openvpn
```

Different distros put files in different locations.

Though on my Fedora system the contents of `openvpn` show the following when I `grep` for "easy-rsa/2.0":

```
$ repoquery -l openvpn | grep -i "easy-rsa/2.0"
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/Makefile
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/README
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-ca
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-dh
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-inter
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-key
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-key-pass
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-key-pkcs12
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-key-server
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-req
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-req-pass
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/clean-all
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/inherit-inter
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/list-crl
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl-0.9.6.cnf
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/openssl.cnf
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/pkitool
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/revoke-full
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/sign-req
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/vars
/usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/whichopensslcnf
```

#### So where are your files?

The next thing to consider when installing software is where are the packages coming from. Are they official? A 3rd party repository? You can check with this command:

```
$ repoquery -i openvpn | grep Repo
Repository  : fedora
```

So this is an official package on my system, and it contains the directories you're asking about.

#### An alternative

The Linux AMI distros that AmazonWS uses are custom versions of CentOS. It probably makes more sense to either install a fullblown version of CentOS or Ubuntu and install the packages using that distro's normal packages vs. these modified ones that Amazon appears to be offering.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Repoquery didn't display any of the directories you listed above. The repository is "amzn-updates", which I think is official. Could the issue potentially be that I have a 64 bit instance?

Comment: It's probably that Amazon doesn't provide this type of package in there repos. This is an official repo for there version of the OS, not an official one to the Fedora/CentOS/RHEL projects.

Comment: According to this tutorial http://porttwentytwo.blogspot.com/2013/01/chromebooks-with-openvpn-on-ec2.html it should be there.

Comment: @J4G - Yeah it's what I said, this tutorial is using a stock installation where the packaged version of openvpn is as I showed you and the tutorial shows you. The amazonws yum repository is some custom thing that Amazon setup, which the package there apparently doesn't include these files.

Comment: Do you know where I can get those files? Do I need to create a new instance? :)

Comment: @J4G - Instance should be fine, I would try installing them directly from a regular yum repo, what distro is this? `lsb_release -a`. You can to a `rpm -ivh http:/....`, for example.

Comment: It's Amazon Linux AMI 64 bit.

Comment: @J4G - yeah that's a custom packaging of some version of CentOS (http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/09/introducing-amazon-linux-ami.html).  I would probably consider either switching the distro, you're likely to run into more issues with the vanilla AMI.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I switched to an Ubuntu instance and OpenVPN installed successfully.

Comment: @J4G - Glad to hear that. Seemed like the easiest path. 8-) Please mark this answer as accepted so others know your issue's been resolved.

Comment: this answer isn't very helpful. Amazon linux made easy-rsa a new package available from the EPEL repo. See @josten's answer below

Comment: @Cfreak - what I provided answered the OP's Q. What josten suggested in using though it works is risky to do since AWS is using a neutered version of CentOS (who knows how they've hobbled it). So by introducing a EPEL CentOS repo into the mix is asking for trouble IMO (20+ years of using RH based distros!)

Comment: Amazon officially supports EPEL. The only change is to enable it in the Yum config. Advice for a user to install an entirely different OS is silly when the fix is so easy.

Comment: @Cfreak - can you please cite where they say they support EPEL within the AWS images?

Answer (score 7):

I came across this issue as well. The solution I found was:

1. Enable the EPEL repo (by default in Amazon Linux AMI it's disabled).
2. Install easy-rsa with: `yum install easy-rsa -y`

You can temporarily enable the repo by adding `--enablerepo=epel` to your `yum` command. So  `yum install easy-rsa -y --enablerepo=epel` will also do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For amazon linux 2, we can enable extra repos with:

```bsh
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

Then install openvpn and easy-rsa with:

```
sudo yum install -y openvpn easy-rsa
```