# How to install OpenVPN client on RHEL 7.3?

Tags: rhel, yum, openvpn, amazon-ec2

I am using `RHEL 7.3` on `AWS EC2`:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
```

I would like to install `OpenVPN` client and was following [these directions](http://www.tecmint.com/setup-openvpn-server-with-linux-and-windows-clients-in-centos-rhel/). I started by `sudo yum update` which completed fine. Then

```
$ sudo yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7                                                                                     | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                                                                                       | 3.5 kB  00:00:00
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common                                                                                      | 3.8 kB  00:00:00
No package epel-release available.
Error: Nothing to do
$ sudo yum install openvpn easy-rsa
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
No package openvpn available.
No package easy-rsa available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I install OpenVPN client? Do I need add another `yum` repo? I also tried the suggestions from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92067/amazon-aws-amazon-ami-installing-openvpn?rq=1), without success.

**UPDATE:**  I was actually able to get past epel. i did `yum-config-manager --enable epel`. Then I also successfully installed easy-rsa: `yum install easy-rsa`. However, when I did yum install openvpn (`yum install openvpn`), i got:

```
Error: Package: openvpn-2.3.14-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: dev >= 3.3.2-5
```

Comment: No:  `Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found` when run that command

Comment: Run `yum install –y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm` then `yum-config-manager --enable epel` update and try to install openvpn

Comment: I got `http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/bd307163e8ee8d968bde0c0214c5d44daaa3419cea7a084bb61b57fd1941b01f-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found`

Comment: I was actually able to get past epel.  i did `sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel`. however, when I did `yum install openvpn`, i got `Error: Package: openvpn-2.3.14-1.el6.x86_64 (epel) Requires: dev >= 3.3.2-5`

Comment: also, see the update I just posted

Comment: i'm confused.  what should I do after `yum remove epel-release`?

Comment: because you have the  epel-6 installed

Comment: OK -- I did `yum remove epel-release`. What do you suggest I do next ?

Comment: what is the output of `yum --enablerepo=epel info openvpn`

Comment: `Error getting repository data for epel, repository not found`

Comment: Centos 7.6 - I also had to run yum-config-manager --enable epel and I was able to install openvpn.  I was already on epel 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `epel-6` repo

```
yum remove epel-release
```

Enable `epel-7` repo:

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.‌​noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.‌​noarch.rpm
```

Or

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
```

edit the `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` file and make sure you have `enabled=1`

or run `yum-config-manager --enable epel`

then install `openvpn`:

```
yum update
yum install openvpn easy-rsa
```

Comment: I had to do the 2nd option for `Enable epel repo` BTW

Comment: Same with "default" curl: `curl -Sso epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 2):

If you're intending to use yum, you might want to skip the wget and just download the package with yum. Otherwise, when you run yum again, it will give you a warning about packages being updated/installed outside of yum.

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```